# BeagleBoard XM with XDS100v2

Tags: arm, beagleboard

I am going to buy a beagleboard xm. The emulator what I got is XDS100v2. Can I able to debug with this in eclipse environment? What everyone suggests in forums is we can use it with Code Composer Studio. But I dont have license for the same,and also the free license provided with XDS100v2 is time limited I guess or atleast it is node locked for the worst case. So has anyone found a way for using XDS100v2 with beagleboard xm?

Comment: nobody knows any info reg xds100v2 compatibility with eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the XDS100 emulators run only with the TI software. You should have gotten a board-locked license with you XDS100v2 - meaning that CCS runs only with exactly this adapter. (See the [CCSv5 licensing FAQ](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Licensing_-_CCS) for more information - it might even be that the normal CCSv5 installation already works with it)

Btw.: Code Composer Studio is based on Eclipse.

OpenOCD might be another way to go. Then you would install one of the GCC toolchains ([code sourcery](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/) or [yagarto](http://www.yagarto.de/), for example), and use OpenOCD. But for that you would need another JTAG adapter, since OpenOCD doesn't support the XDS series.